# Wordpress custom post by custom fileds

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type and a custom field: `expired_date`.
I want to display that posts are not expired, so basically I want to check that if `expired_date > current_date`, the post will display.

How can I perform this WordPress loop query?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'job_listing'

    );

    query_posts($args);
    ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Can you please help me how to check that in custom post query.

Comment: Correct the Wordpress spelling!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'meta_key' => 'the_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'the_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$your_custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

hope will help :)

Comment: what do you want. you mean query not getting correct posts which you have ?

Comment: i have used above query and print last executed query and it prints
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (6461) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
which is wrong

Comment: what is the issue ?